# Is there anyway to pass multiple values to a single argument

Tags: python, pexpect

I have a function defined like this:

```
def cmd_success(cmd_session, success_cmd, failure_cmd=None):
    ....
    ....
```

I am calling that function here:

```
for command in commands:
success = cmd_success(session, str_prompt, 'Invalid')
if success == False:
    print "Invalid Command"
    sys.exit()
```

Currently, it is only checking for 'invalid' string but I would like to check for 'Error', 'Incomplete'.  For many reason, I can not change code in cmd_success function so I was looking for a way to do it during function call.

Something like this:

```
for command in commands:
    success = cmd_success(session, str_prompt, ['Invalid', 'Error', Incomplete')
    if success == False:
        print "Invalid Command"
        sys.exit()
```

That doesn't work and gives me this:

```
TypeError: got <type 'tuple'> (['Invalid', 'Error', 'Incomplete' ]) as pattern, must be one of: <type 'basestring'>, pexpect.EOF, pexpect.TIMEOUT
```

Is there anyway it can look for all three strings? The argument is 'failure_cmd' and it is expecting only 1 string but I would like to have all 3 strings passed so f any one of them is found, success is set to false.

Thanks
Damon

Comment: Do you need all 3 at once or do you need one of them at a time?

Comment: Yes, a functions arguments can be any value, including a list.  But you're also going to have to iterate over that list to get what you want.  Post the entire error back trace, and I think you'll see that's failing inside cmd_success because you're attempting to treat your list like a string.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this without modifying `cmd_success` to deal with the multiple values. How do you expect it to do so when it's clearly expecting a single value now? Some sort of magic? Self-modifying code based on telepathy? Think about it: *I have a recipe that requires one large egg, slightly beaten. I want it to work when I thrown in a dozen eggs still in the carton.*

Comment: @Koralarts, invalid command will either have Invalid, error or incomplete.  So if it sees anyone of them, it will return false.  So, I believe it needs to go thru each string one by one.

Comment: Can you show how `cmd_success()` uses its `failure_cmd` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to its documentation, `pexpect` takes a regular expression as its pattern parameter. It is possible that a regular expression might work for the `cmd_success()` pattern, also.

Try this:

```
success = cmd_success(session, str_prompt, 'Invalid|Error|Incomplete')
```

Comment: Right on mate  :)  I shoulda tried tried .. worked like a charm !!!!!!!!!  @Ken White, Some sort of magic? "Self-modifying code based on telepathy?"  .... behold its "|"